# exception while Read very large file > 300 MB

Tags: java, file

My task is to **open a large file in READ&WRITE mode** and i need to **search some portion** of text in that file by searching starting and end point.
Then i need to write that searched area of text to a new file and delete that portion from the original file.

The above process i will do more times.
So I thought that for these process, it will be easy by loading the file into memory by **CharBuffer** and can search easily by **MATCHER** class.
But im getting **HeapSpace exception** while reading, even though i increased to 900MB by executing like below
**java -Xms128m -Xmx900m readLargeFile**
My code is

```
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(fFile).getChannel();
CharBuffer chrBuff = Charset.forName("8859_1").newDecoder().decode(fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size()));
```

> For that above code every one
>   suggested me that its a bad idea to
>   load everything into memory and If
>   file size is 300 MB means, it will be
>   600MB due to charSet.

So above is my task, then now suggest me some **efficient** ways.
Note that **my file size will be more** and using **JAVA** only i've to do these things.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: 300MB into memory???????

Comment: Even in '09 most PCs have more than 300 MB. Now its surprising cheap. You can buy a PC with 16 GB for less than $1000.

Answer (score 5):

You definitely do NOT want to load a 300MB file into a single large buffer with Java.  The way you're doing things is supposed to be more efficient for large files than just using normal I/O, but when you run a `Matcher` against an entire file mapped into memory as you are, you can very easily exhaust memory.

First, your code memory maps the file into memory ... this will consume 300 Meg of memory in your virtual address space as the file is `mmap`ed into it, although this is outside the heap.  (Note that the 300 Meg of virtual address space is tied up *until the `MappedByteBuffer` is garbage collected*.  See below for discussion.  The JavaDoc for [`map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long)) warns you about this.)  Next, you create a `ByteBuffer` backed by this `mmap`ed file.  This should be fine, as it's just a "view" of the `mmap`ed file and should thus take minimal extra memory.  It will be a small object in the heap with a "pointer" to a large object outside the heap.  Next, you decode this into a `CharBuffer`, which means you make a **copy** of the 300 MB buffer, but you make a 600 MB copy (on the heap) because a `char` is 2 bytes.

To respond to a comment, and looking at the JDK Source code to be sure, when you call `map()` as the OP is, you do in fact map the *entire* file into memory.  Looking at openJDK 6 b14 Windows native code `sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.c`, it first calls [`CreateFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537(VS.85).aspx), then calls [`MapViewOfFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366761(VS.85).aspx).  Looking at this source, if you ask to map the whole file into memory, this method will do exactly as you ask.  To quote MSDN:

> Mapping a file makes the specified portion of a file visible in the
> address space of the calling process.
>
> For files that are larger than the address space, you can only map a small portion
> of the file data at one time. When the first view is complete, you can unmap it and
> map a new view.

The way the OP is calling map, the "specified portion" of the file is the entire file. This won't contribute to *heap* exhaustion, but it can contribute to virtual address space exhaustion, which is still an OOM error.  This can kill your application just as thoroughly as running out of heap.

Finally, when you make a `Matcher`, the `Matcher` potentially makes more copies of this 600 MB `CharBuffer`, depending on how you use it.  Ouch.  That's a lot of memory used by a small number of objects!  Given a `Matcher`, **every time** you call `toMatchResult()`, you'll make a `String` copy of the **entire** `CharBuffer`.  Also, **every time** you call `replaceAll()`, at best you will make a `String` copy of the entire `CharBuffer`.  At worst you will make a `StringBuffer` that will slowly be expanded to the full size of the `replaceAll` result (applying a lot of memory pressure on the heap), and then make a `String` from that.

Thus, if you call `replaceAll` on a `Matcher` against a 300 MB file, and your match is found, then you'll first make a series of ever-larger `StringBuffer`s until you get one that is 600 MB.  Then you'll make a `String` copy of this `StringBuffer`.  This can quickly and easily lead to heap exhaustion.

Here's the bottom line:  `Matcher`s are not optimized for working on very large buffers. You can very easily, and without planning to, make a number of very large objects.  I discovered this when doing something similar enough to what you're doing and encountering memory exhaustion, then looking at the source code for `Matcher`.

NOTE:  There is no `unmap` call.  Once you call [`map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long)), the virtual address space outside the heap tied up by the `MappedByteBuffer` is stuck there until the `MappedByteBuffer` is garbage collected.  As a result, you will be unable to perform certain operations on the file (delete, rename, ...) until the `MappedByteBuffer` is garbage collected.  If call map enough times on different files, but don't have sufficient memory pressure in the heap to force a garbage collection, you can out of memory outside the heap.  For a discussion, see [Bug 4724038](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4724038).

As a result of all of the discussion above, if you will be using it to make a `Matcher` on large files, and you will be using `replaceAll` on the `Matcher`, then memory mapped I/O is probably not the way to go.  It will simply create too many large objects on the heap as well as using up a lot of your virtual address space outside the heap.  Under 32 bit Windows, you have only 2GB (or if you have changed settings, 3GB) of virtual address space for the JVM, and this will apply significant memory pressure both inside and outside the heap.

I apologize for the length of this answer, but I wanted to be thorough.  If you think any part of the above is wrong, please comment and say so.  I **will not** do retaliatory downvotes.  I am *very* positive that all of the above is accurate, but if something is wrong, I want to know.

Comment: It should be noted that FileChannel.map() returns a Direct Byte Buffer.  While yes, it is mapped, it is not necessarily loaded into memory, and hence not contributing to any potential memory exhaustion issues and not part of your 1.5GB claim.

Comment: @Stu Thompson:  Look at the JDK source code.  It is in fact loaded into memory -- at least initially into the virtual address space of the process, and as it is accessed, it certainly occupies real memory.  However, it is most likely outside the heap.

Answer (score 2):

Does your search pattern match more than one line? If not then the easiest solution is to read line by line :). Simple really

But if the search pattern matches multiple lines then you need to let us know because searching line by line will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Claims that the FileChannel.map will load the entire file into memory are faulty, with reference to the [MappedByteBuffer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) that FileChannel.map() returns.  It is a 'Direct Byte Buffer', it not exhaust your memory *(Direct Byte Buffers use the OS virtual memory subsystem to page data in and out of memory as required, allowing one to address much larger chunks of memory as they were physical RAM.)*  But then again, a single MBB will only work for files to ~2GB.

Try this:

```
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(fFile).getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

CharBuffer chrBuff = mbb.asCharBuffer();
```

It will not load the entire file into memory, and the chrBuff is only a *view* of the backing MappedByteBuffer, and not a copy.

I'm not sure how to handle the decoding, though.

Comment: You're not exactly correct.  Look at the JDK source code.  The entire file will be mapped into the Java process's virtual address space.  In 32-bit Windows, you only have up to 2 GB of virtual address space unless you have made some changes.  If you allocate a large heap, you leave less room for stuff outside the heap, and you can easily run into problems.  We don't know what else the OP's program is doing, and what other native resources are allocated outside the heap.

Comment: In addition, your suggestion won't work at all. When you call mbb.asCharBuffer(), you are not doing any decoding. You are just treating the ByteBuffer as a CharBuffer of half the number of characters. That is, when you get the first character, it will read TWO BYTES from the ByteBuffer and treat them as one char. This will work only if the file in question is using a 2-byte encoding scheme, which is NOT the case for ISO-8859-1, the encoding used by the OP. Look at the source code and read MSDN. This doesn't do what you thought it did.

Comment: By the way, the reason that a single MBB will only work for files up to about 2 GB is that that's the limit of your virtual address space under Window by default.  A mapped file is absolutely mapped into your virtual address space, but outside the heap.  Also, note that there is no unmap() call.  You have to wait for the DirectByteBuffer to be garbage collected.  See http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4724038

Comment: 1) At no point did I or the OP mention 32-bit Windows, sooo...your Windows-specific may be valid, but not for the ambiguous topic here.  Think bigger.
2) This limit for 32-bit Windows is for *all* memory allocation by the JVM (any single processes, as I understand, on Windows) and not just a single MappedByteBuffer.  
3) Individual MappedByteBuffers are limited to ~2GB on ALL platforms because FileChannel.map's 'size' parameter is a Java int...even on a 64-bit OS with >2GB of addressable space
4) MappedByteBuffers are NOT allocated on the heap, so your heap argument is mute.

Comment: @Eddie comment #2: I specifically did not claim to solve coding problem.  And I don't do MSDN as I don't develop on or for Windows.

Comment: @Eddie comment #3:  1) Again, think bigger than just Windows;  2) I repeat: FileChannel.map takes a Java int for size, and that is a cross-platform limit for any single MBB;  3) The unmap bug has a potential workarounds, if one is actually needed.  My folks, including myself, use MBBs in our applications without issue.  The bug does not necessarily negate the utility and performance gains that can be had with MBBs.

Comment: @Eddie: And, lastly, this bug is Windows specific.  We do not know the platform the Questioner is on, we do not know if he is on a 64-bit OS.  Assume nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Using a buffer to read a bulk of file one time 
There is one trick:
each time your  read a new string into buffer, make sure it has a overlap of length l, which is the length of substring
l = length(substring);
while (not eof) do
begin
   if  find(buffer,substring) return TRUE;
   buffer[0..l] = substring;
   buffer[l+1, end] = read_new_chars_intobuffer;
end

Answer (score -2):

In my case, adding `-Djava.compiler=NONE` after the classpath can solve the problem.