# java: how to search a string in a big file?

Tags: java, file, io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [exception while Read very large file > 300 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985076/exception-while-read-very-large-file-300-mb)

Now, i want to search a string from a big file(>=300M). Because the file is big so i can't load it into memory.

What kind of ways can be provided to handle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584540/read-and-process-big-text-file-in-java

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

1. Depending on your target OS, you might be able to hand off this task to a system utility such as [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) (which is already optimized for this sort of work) and simply parse the output.
2. Even if the file were small enough to be contained in memory, you'd have to read it from disk either way. So, you can simply read it in, one line at a time, and compare your string to the contents as they are read. If your app only needs to find the **first** occurrence of a string in a target file, this has the benefit that, if the target string appears early in the file, you save having to read the entire file just to find something that's in the first half of the file.
3. Unless you have an upper limit on your app's memory usage (i.e. it must absolutely fit within 128 MB of RAM, etc.) then you can also increase the amount of RAM that the JVM will take up when you launch your app. But, because of the inefficiency of this (in terms of time, and disk I/O, as pointed out in #2), this is unlikely to be the course that you'll want to take, regardless of file size.

Answer (score 1):

I would memory map the file.  This doesn't use much heap (< 1 KB), regardless of the file size (up to 2 GB) and takes about 10 ms on most systems.

```
FileChannel ch = new FileInputStream(fileName).getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mbb = ch.map(ch.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0L, ch.size());
```

This works provided you have a minimum of 4 KB free (and your file is less than 2 GB long)

Comment: The nice thing is it is left to the OS to determine how much is in main memory (in the background) You can code as if everything is available immediately and not have to worry about how much free memory you have or which pages you no longer need.