# find/replace with charBuffer

Tags: java, pattern-matching, nio, replace

I'm new to the NIO classes; I'm working on some pattern matching with (possibly) very large text files, and so far I'm reading data in from the file by mapping its channel to a byteBuffer, which is then converted to a charBuffer. My question is, with the charBuffer's MapMode set to READ_WRITE, is there a way to directly modify the charBuffer as I am processing it, ala matcher.replaceAll()? Or do I need to loop through with matcher.find() and manually replace each instance of the pattern?

Comment: Can the pattern span the whole file or just a line?

Comment: Possiby longer than a line so processing it one line at a time is out, unfotunately.

Comment: You can do it, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985076/exception-while-read-very-large-file-300-mb), not so advisable. Better look for **sed**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first just try reading in the entire file and do a find and replace and see if the performance is acceptable.  If not, try to read in enough of the text to create a match and then do a replace on that portion of the text.  Depending on the pattern/performance you may need to write a custom parser instead.

Comment: I didn't realize so many copies were made during the process; I was under the impression that using a charBuffer was simply a different view of the byteBuffer, and tripling the memory usage during the decoding process is a bit too steep for my purposes. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: If reading in the entire file is too slow, do you know of any good resources on creating one's own parser?

Comment: A [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) is pretty easy to write and I would start there.  For complex parsing and best performance however you can look into using a [parse table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) instead.  You will find lots of good resources online since parsing is a well-studied problem in CS.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Matcher.replaceAll()` returns a new String. It doesn't modify the source string. Putting your `MappedByteBuffer` into READ_WRITE mode can't change that in the slightest.
2. You can't in general replace strings in files with other strings unless the old and new string are the same length. So you have to write a new file in any case.
3. I agree with @Garret Hall's answer. I would get it working with a `BufferedReader` and then decide whether I really had a performance problem.